# Create mount point and mounting partition

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, uefi

Question about mounting partitions:

do I need first to create mount point for EFI partition, then mount:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi          #Create EFI partition mount point
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   #Mount EFI partition
```

or I can mount straight without mount point creation?

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   #Mount EFI partition
```

In most examples I don't see the mount moint creation prior mounting partition.

Comment: /boot/efi is already mounted in /etc/fstab. No need to try and do it again. And yes, you need to create mount points, if they don't already exist, before trying to mount.

Comment: when you need to recover system and boot from LiveCD image: how do you know that /boot/efi is already mounted in /etc/fstab?

Comment: That's a different question than what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The `mount` command mounts a partition on a certain directory. That directory must exist. So you need to create the desired mount point if it does yet not exist. If it does already exist, then you do not need to, nor can you, create the mount point.

Comment: what's difference between `mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` and `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`?

Comment: Different mount point obviously, but that is a different question.